# RXJS wait for other Observable

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I need to subscribe to a result, but wait for intermediate operations to finish before getting the result. The trick is that I "visit" my result to populate it:

```
// a service that gets a model
service.getModel(): Observable<MyModel>;

// I need to enrich my model before consuming it
service.getModel()
    .makeSureAllCodesAreFetched(data => visitModel(model))
    .subscribe(data => console.log("data is ready: ", data));

// a visitor that visits the model tree and enriches the leaves
// recursively visit the branches
visitModel(model: MyModel) {
    if (model.isLeaf) {
       // on condition, call a service to fetch additional data
       service.fetchCodes(model.codeKey).subscribe(codes => model.codes = codes);
    } else {
        model.properties.forEach(prop: MyModel => visit(prop));
    }
}
```

I tried to play with merges and forkJoin() without success. I just want to make sure that all calls to `fetchCodes()`, regardless of the result, are done before my data is subscribed to.

Comment: Please edit the question and add what you tried with `forkJoin()` - you might have been close to a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it's not the cleanest to my opinion.

```
// a service that gets a model
service.getModel(): Observable<MyModel>;

// I need to enrich my model before consuming it
service.getModel()
    .pipe(
        mergeMap(data => forkJoin(visitModel(model))))
    .subscribe(data => console.log("data is ready: ", data[0]));

// a visitor that visits the model tree and enriches the leaves
// recursively visit the branches
visitModel(model: MyModel, obs?: Observable<MyModel>[]): Observable<MyModel>[] {
    if (obs === undefined) {
        obs = [];
        obs.push(of(model)); // make sure the very first Observable is the root
    }
    if (model.isLeaf) {
       // on condition, call a service to fetch additional data
       // push Observable result in the array
       obs.push(service.fetchCodes(model.codeKey).map(codes => {
           model.codes = codes;
           return model;
       }));
    } else {
        model.properties.forEach(prop: MyModel => visit(prop, obs)); // recursive call
    }
    return obs;
}
```

My visitor will actually append all the calls to `fetchCodes()` into an array of `Observables` and return it. That way `forkJoin` will wait for all the calls to be completed. The trick (and dirty part) is that I must make sure the first `Observable` is actually the root element I am interested in.